# subclass method overwriting in python

Tags: python, overriding, subclass

I write a test code of python like:

```
class Parent(object):
    @classmethod
    def dispatch(klass):
        print 'klass = %s' % klass
        return klass().__dispatch()
    def __dispatch(self):
        print 'This Parent.__dispatch()'
        print self


class Child(Parent):
    def __dispatch(self):
        print 'This Child.__dispatch()'
        print self


if __name__=='__main__':
    print 'Calling Parent.dispatch() ...\n'
    Parent.dispatch()
    print ''
    print 'Calling Child.dispatch() ...\n'
    Child.dispatch()
    print '\n-END'
```

And the output is:

```
 Calling Parent.dispatch() ...

 klass = <class '__main__.Parent'> 
 This Parent.__dispatch()
 <__main__.Parent object at 0x0000000002D3A2E8>

 Calling Child.dispatch() ...

 klass = <class '__main__.Child'> 
 This Parent.__dispatch()
 <__main__.Child object at 0x0000000002D3A2E8>

 -END
```

It's very strange why the overwrote method '__dispatch(self)' of Child class was not called.

Does anyone can explain about this?

Thank you.

Comment: avoiding to define double scored __attributes is a good python practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methodnames that start with a double underscore are automatically mangled; internally, the string `_ClassName` is prepended to the method name:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __bar(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> Foo.__dict__.keys()
['__dict__', '__module__', '__weakref__', '__doc__', '_Foo__bar']
```

This renaming also is done for anything *referencing* this method name in any of the other methods in the class.

Thus, your `__dispatch()` method is renamed to `_Parent__dispatch()`, and the `dispatch()` method is *altered* to call `self._Parent__dispatch()` instead. Similarly, your `Child` class has a `_Child__dispatch()` method, and it thus *does not override the `_Parent__dispatch()` method of it's super-class*.

This is why you see the results you see; rename your `__dispatch()` methods to `_dispatch()` (only one underscore) and it'll work as expected.

Why does python do this? It's a form of providing private attributes and methods, that cannot be accidentally overridden by classes that inherit from them. See [private name mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) in the Python expression reference.

The [PEP 8 Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has this to say about private name mangling:

> If your class is intended to be subclassed, and you have attributes
>   that you do not want subclasses to use, consider naming them with
>   double leading underscores and no trailing underscores. This invokes
>   Python's name mangling algorithm, where the name of the class is
>   mangled into the attribute name. This helps avoid attribute name
>   collisions should subclasses inadvertently contain attributes with the
>   same name.
>
> Note 1: Note that only the simple class name is used in the mangled
>   name, so if a subclass chooses both the same class name and attribute
>   name, you can still get name collisions.
>
> Note 2: Name mangling can make certain uses, such as debugging and
>   `__getattr__()`, less convenient. However the name mangling algorithm
>   is well documented and easy to perform manually.
>
> Note 3: Not everyone likes name mangling. Try to balance the need to
>   avoid accidental name clashes with potential use by advanced callers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the methods _dispatch instead of __dispatch?

The point is that __dispatch is internally translated into _NameOfTheClass_dispatch (or something of the kind to give a sort of 'private' member function behavior). This is the reason why your override fails.

If you use _dispatch the name of the member function is not affected by the underscore and the program behaves as you wish.